WebDriverException/The requested URL could not be retrieved/Access Denied Error for Selenium chrome webdriver
I am trying to run selenium code for chrome browser in python but facing below issue. I am providing the proxy server details correctly and providing the chrome driver path. But the webdriver.Chrome is throwing access denied error.
Python 3.12
Selenium version: 4.18.1
urllib3 version: 2.2.1
Chrome driver version: 96.0.4664.45
Code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={http_proxy}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

Error Message:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta type="copyright" content="Copyright (C) 1996-2015 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
 /*
 * Copyright (C) 1996-2016 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors
 *
 * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and includes
 * contributions from numerous individuals and organizations.
 * Please see the COPYING and CONTRIBUTORS files for details.
 */

/*
 Stylesheet for Squid Error pages
 Adapted from design by Free CSS Templates
 http://www.freecsstemplates.org
 Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License
*/

.....
</head><body id=ERR_ACCESS_DENIED>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://localhost:58280/session">http://localhost:58280/session</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Access Denied.</b></p>
</blockquote>

Checked the proxy configurations are correct
I tried using selenium version 3.14
Tried setting to no_proxy

your proxy is intercepting the driver's commands to the browser.  (unless you are testing a localhost'ed website?) This is probably not what you want.  If you are trying to proxy the browser's requests to the internet, just set it machine-wide.  You don't need to configure Selenium or WebDriver to use it.

also check your hosts file as the webdriver will run as localhost.  If your proxy also runs as localhost, you'll want to change one or the other to 127.0.0.1
